# [VHDL]Why the need for an auxiliary variable in sum loop

Tags: loops, vhdl

I wrote a process which sums the contents of an array of floats. The array has length 6 and has the same value 6 times, 0.5. So the sum of the array is 3.0.

The process is like this:

```
signal array_sum  : float32 := to_float(0.0);
begin
....

sum_proc:process(clk)
begin
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        for i in 0 to size_array - 1 loop
             array_sum <= array_sum + array_float(i);
        end loop;
    result <= array_sum;
    end if;
end process;
```

the result of this is 1.5..

However if I use an auxiliary value, it works and the result is 3.0:

```
sum_proc:process(clk)
    variable sum_aux : float32;
begin
    sum_aux := to_float(0.0);
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        for i in 0 to size_array - 1 loop
             sum_aux := sum_aux + array_float(i);
        end loop;
    result <= sum_aux;
    end if;
end process;
```

I can't seem to understand why this happens. Can someone explain please?

Also, the `sum_aux` initialization to 0.0 needs to be done inside the begin, else the result is not correct. Is this because only the code inside the `begin` is executed multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer these questions in reverse order:

The line `sum_aux := to_float(0.0);` is required, because without this, the variable will hold the value set the last time the process ran. Remember, your summation line looks like `sum_aux := sum_aux +`, so without a reset, it's just going to get bigger and bigger.

Your first example doesn't work, because signal assignments are only scheduled to take place in the next delta cycle, they don't actually happen at the moment they are reached. Another delta cycle will occur after all processes have run in the current cycle.

With this in mind, your 'sum' just keeps scheduling the same addition of `0.0 + 0.5`, before then scheduling the assignment of the *current* value of  `array_sum` to `result`. I would expect the following sequence:

1. The first clock edge is observed. `0.0 + 0.5` evaluated *n* times. The final assignment of a particular signal in the process takes priority, so the last of these results (`0.5`) is scheduled. `array_sum` is still `0.0` at this point.
2. The `result` is scheduled to be assigned this value `0.0`.
3. Process ends; scheduled signal assignments now take place.
4. The next clock edge is observed. `0.5 + 0.5` evaluated *n* times. The last of these results (`1.0`) is scheduled. `array_sum` is still `0.5` at this point.
5. The `result` is assigned this value `0.5`.
6. Process ends; scheduled signal assignments now take place.

And so on. I would then expect `result` to keep increasing by `0.5` on each subsequent clock edge.

Comment: Great explanation!Ty very much